# Does the Java ArrayList.clear() method behave consistently?

Tags: java, arraylist, instance

Does the clear() method in Java null the elements in ArrayList or just free its references and keep values alive.

I am assigning all objects in ArrayList to another object and then clearings it. After clearing it the assigned references to another objects are giving inconsistent results. On the other hand if I create a new ArrayList object instead of clearing it works fine.

```
ArrayList <Condition> conditionList = new ArrayList<Condition>();    
Risk riskObject = new Risk();
for (int i =0; i<10; i++) {         
    if(some-condition){
                    addElemetsToConditionList();

                }else{
                    addElemetsToConditionList();            
                    riskObject.setConditions(conditionList); // Setter which sets condition list to risk object. 

                    Risk newRiskObject = new Risk();
                    riskObject = newRiskObject;

//                  conditionList = new ArrayList<Condition>();
                    conditionList.clear();

                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `getting inconsistent results.`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you  @Eran i mean ,
 Suppose if I have assigned 10 elements to conditionList and then assigning conditionList to riskObject and in next iteration I am assigning 5 elements to conditions after completion of for loop when I print Json of riskObject its having 5 conditions 2 both riskObjects where in it should have 10 conditions for first and 5 for second. But when i Comment conditionList.clear(); and use  conditionList = new ArrayList<Condition>(); its showing correct results.

Comment: @Zebronix_777 Your setConditions method should create a copy of the List passed to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, it `null`s all the elements in it's backing buffer (removing the references that it has) and set it's size to `0`

```
/**
 * Removes all of the elements from this list.  The list will
 * be empty after this call returns.
 */
public void clear() {
    modCount++;

    // clear to let GC do its work
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        elementData[i] = null;

    size = 0;
}
```

Any references you might have to the data external are still valid, it's just the `ArrayList` no longer maintains a reference to them

I believe your problem is here...

```
riskObject.setConditions(conditionList);
```

You're passing the instance of the `ArrayList` to the `riskObject` and then clearing it, it is sharing the same instance.

Instead, you could create a new instance of a `ArrayList`

```
riskObject.setConditions(new ArrayList(conditionList));
```

Which makes a copy of the contents of the `conditionList`, so when you clear it, the reference you passed to `riskObject` won't be effected or, as you have already done, create a new `ArrayList` for your continuing processing, which ever seems most logical to you.

Comment: @Zebronix_777 Glad it could help.  Eran raises another good point which might need to be considered, but that will come down your requirements

Answer (score 3):

If `riskObject.setConditions(conditionList);` stores a reference to `conditionList` in the `riskObject` instance, calling `conditionList.clear()` would also clear the elements of the list reference held by the `riskObject` instance, since it refers to the same instance.

You can avoid it by creating a defensive copy :

```
public void setConditions (List<Condition> conditions)
{
    this.conditions = new ArrayList<> (conditions);
}
```

This is better than passing a copy of the List to the `setConditions` method of the `Risk` class, since it doesn't depend on the implementation of the code that uses the `Risk` class to function properly.

Comment: IMHO You should pass a copy of the `ArrayList` to the object, this otherwise suggests some knowledge of the implementation of the `RiskObject` which the caller probably shouldn't have - but that's just me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I can give a counter argument - the Risk object should function properly even if it's not passed a copy of the ArrayList. It should make sure by itself that its mutable members are not exposed to outside classes.

Comment: This is true, but if the implementation changes, how do the callers know?  Maybe both methods are correct, I just don't like making assumptions about what some other class might or might not "expect" - but that's just me ;)

Comment: @Eran your answer is also correct but in a way we are creating different copy of arraylist so it doesn't make any sense you make it at calling end or receiving end (in setter). So what is the advantage of handling it at receiving end.

Comment: @Zebronix_777 `so it doesn't make any sense you make it at calling end or receiving end` - did you mean to say it makes no difference where you make the copy? I think it's better do create it in the setter, since it ensures the proper behavior of the Risk class, no matter how it is used. It also saves some code if you call setConditions in multiple places, and it prevents the risk of the user of the Risk class forgetting to create a copy in some of the calls to setConditions.